# I am New in Flutter. I want to display JSON Data as List in flutter but I do not know how to Coding for show JSON data as a List in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I want to show this JSON data as a List in Flutter. I have JSON data but I do not know how to do Code for show JSON data as a List in Flutter.

This is JSON File :

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Ramesh Shah",
    "Activity_Type": "Highseverity",
    "Description": "Try to Send data using Chrome",
    "Date": "2022-02-03T11:31:00Z"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setState(() {
  data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
});
```

You can use JSON decoder to create a flutter object from JSON array

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          body: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return new Card(
                child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```